# Column is getting represented as boolean instead of characters

Tags: r

I want to convert the boolean column into character column. I have tried
as.character(df$column.name). It has converted column to character but values are missing.

Input data is:

| date | comment |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-18 | Cancel |
| 2022-11-28 | prepaid |
| 2022-01-01 | Mistake |

Output should be same as input but I am getting the output as

| date | comment |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-18 |  |
| 2022-11-28 |  |
| 2022-01-01 |  |

I am getting blanks for complete column.

Comment: An effective way to include a date set is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: Your comment column is not boolean. Firstly, there is no boolean type in R, only logical vectors. Secondly, it is not a logical vector because it contains values other than "TRUE" and "FALSE". Do you mean "factor"? Thirdly, we have no idea what happens and cannot help you until you post some example data.

Comment: I know column is not boolean but it is showing as boolean to me